# Add hours value to DateTime column in PowerQuery

Tags: powerquery

I'm facing a boring problem.
I have two columns into my Power Query table

1- date/time --> 10/01/2023 04:30:00
2- Hours --> -2

Whath is the formula that convert 10/01/2023 04:30:00 into 10/01/2023 02:30:00, so Date/time + Hours?

Answer (score 1):

try add column .. custom column ... with formula

```
= [Column1]+#duration(0,[Column2],0,0)
```

replacing [Column1] with the name of your existing datetime, and replacing [Column2] with the name of the column that has the number of hours you want to add

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add 6 hours with the existing datetime column

```
existing_colun + #duration(0,6,0,0)

[DateTime] + #duration(0,6,0,0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to replace the original value in your first column and avoiding to create a new column, you can replace the values in-place like this:

```
= Table.TransformColumns(source, {"Column1", each _ + #duration(0, [Column2], 0, 0) })
```